# Generic REST client in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, akka-http, play-json

I'm a bit new to Scala and I'm trying to write a generic client for a RESTful api I would like to use. I'm able to provide concrete `Reads[T]` and `Writes[T]` for the specific case classes I would like to instantiate my client for, however the compiler expects to find a `Reads[T]` and `Writes[T]` for any type, not just the types I'm using. Some code to illustrate (I've omitted irrelevant sections):

My generic client:

```
class RestModule[T](resource: String, config: Config) ... with JsonSupport{
...
def create(item: T): Future[T] = {
    val appId = config.apiId
    val path = f"/$apiVersion%s/applications/$appId%s/$resource"

    Future {
      val itemJson = Json.toJson(item)
      itemJson.toString.getBytes
    } flatMap {
      post(path, _)
    } flatMap { response =>
      val status = response.status
      val contentType = response.entity.contentType

      status match {
        case Created => contentType match {
          case ContentTypes.`application/json` => {
            Unmarshal(response.entity).to[T]
          }
          case _ => Future.failed(new IOException(f"Wrong Content Type: $contentType"))
        }
        case _ => Future.failed(new IOException(f"HTTP Error: $status"))
      }
    }
...
}
```

JsonSupprt Trait:

```
trait JsonSupport {
    implicit val accountFormat = Json.format[Account]
}
```

I'm only ever instantiating as `RestModule[Account]("accounts",config)` but I get the error

```
Error:(36, 32) No Json serializer found for type T. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
  val itemJson = Json.toJson(item)
                           ^
```

Why does the compiler think it needs a Writes for type T when T can only ever be of type Account? Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the compiler doesn't like what you're doing is to do with how `implicit` parameters are resolved and more crucially *when* they are resolved.

Consider the snippet,

```
Object MyFunc {
   def test()(implicit s: String): String = s
}
```

The `implicit` parameter only gets resolved by the parameter when the function is called, and basically is expanded as,

```
MyFunc.test()(resolvedImplicit)
```

In your particular case you actually call the function requiring the `implicit` and hence it looks for an `implicit` of `T` at that point in time. Since it can't find one in scope it fails to compile.

In order to solve this issue, simply add the `implicit` parameter to the `create` method to tell the compiler to resolve it when you call `create` rather than `toJson` within `create`.

Furthermore we can use scala's implicit rules to get the behaviour that you want.

Let's take your trait `Reads`,

```
trait Reads[A] {
}

object MyFunc {
  def create[A](a: A)(implicit reads: Reads[A]): Unit = ???
}
```

as we said befeore you can call it if the `implicit` is in scope. However, in this particular case where you have predefined reads we can actually put it in the companion object,

```
object Reads {
  implicit val readsInt: Reads[Int] = ???
  implicit val readsString: Reads[String] = ???
}
```

This way when `create` is called, the user doesn't need to import or define any `implicit` `vals` when `A` is `Int` or `String` because scala automatically looks in the companion object for any implicit definitions if it can't find one in the current scope.

Comment: Thanks! What you say works but is there a way I can avoid changing the interface or having the caller be responsible for providing the implicit ```Reads``` and ```Writes```? That's what I was going for by putting them in the trait, ideally I'd like to make them available implicitly somewhere in the class without callers having to worry about putting them in scope.

Comment: Certainly. What you can do is to add the `implicit` parameter but add your own `implicit` `val`s of `Reads` and `Writes` within their own companion object. That way when someone uses `create` scala will look into your predefined `Reads` and `Writes` first.

Comment: Great thanks, I tested this in a separate project and see how it works now. Although in this specific case, ```Reads[A]``` and ```Writes[A]``` are provided by a library (play-json) along with a companion object, so I've made a companion object to go with ```RestModule``` instead which contains the required implicts which clients should import prior to calling ```create```. It's not as transparent as I'd like it to be but it works :)